# Are there more complex functions to call from within Solidity (Smart Contracts/Ethereum)?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am wondering besides these below mathematical expressions are there any other functions available to call inside a smart contract?  Like math functions, like pi, sin, cosine, random() etc?

I am wondering if one can write smart contracts that require a little more than just basic arithmetic.

Below Image is taken from this page:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/cheatsheet.html#function-visibility-specifiers

[image: CheatSheet Solidity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidity doesn't natively support storing floating point numbers both in storage and memory, probably because the EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine; underlying layer) doesn't support it.

It allows working with them to some extent such as `uint two = 3 / 1.5;`.

So most floating point operations are usually done by defining a `uint256` (256bit unsigned integer) number and another number defining the decimal length.

For example token contracts generally use 18 decimal places:

```
uint8 decimals = 18;

uint256 one  = 1000000000000000000;
uint256 half =  500000000000000000;
```

---

There are some third-party libraries for calculating trigonometric functions ([link](https://github.com/Sikorkaio/sikorka/blob/master/contracts/trigonometry.sol)), working with date time ([link](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary/blob/master/contracts/BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary.sol)) and other use cases, but the native language currently doesn't support many of these features.

---

As for generating random numbers: No native function, but you can calculate a modulo of some pseudo-random variables such as `block.hash` and `block.timestamp`. Mind that these values can be (to some extent) manipulated by a miner publishing the currently mined block.

It's not recommended to use them in apps that work with money (pretty much most of smart contracts), because if the incentive is big enough, there can be a dishonest miner who can use the advantage of knowing the values before rest of the network and being able to modify them to some extent to their own benefit.

Example:

```
// a dishonest miner can publish a block with such params,
// that will result in the condition being true
// and their own tx to be the first one in the block that executes this function
function win10ETH() external {
    if (uint256(blockhash(block.number)) % 12345 == 0) {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(10 ether);
    }
}
```

If you need a random number that is not determinable by a miner, you can use the oracle approach, where an external app (called oracle) listens to transactions in a predefined format (generally also from&to specific addresses), performs an off-chain action (such as generating a random number, retrieving a google search result, or basically anything) and afterwards sends another transaction to your contract, containing the result of the off-chain action.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, solidity is also missing a loop function like 'while' or 'for' from what I see. the solidity language is less complex than Fortran77.

Comment: @AndiAna There are loops `while`, `do {} while` and `for`. Mind that if you do some storage operation in a loop, it's going to be costly (each storage write costs 5k gas), so they are practically used only with a small finite number of iterations, or in read-only functions (`view` and `pure` state modifiers) that don't consume gas fees.