# Solidity - ParserError: Expected ';' but got '['

Tags: ethereum, solidity

** I'm getting an error on the below mentioned line. ParserError: Expected ';' but got '[' . I'm using solidity version 0.8.7 in remix editor. Please help me regarding this problem **

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;     //version
contract Lottery 
{
    address public manager;
    address [] public players;

 constructor() 
 {
   manager = msg.sender;
 }

 function enter() public payable                  
 {
   require(msg.value > .01 ether);                                        
   players.push(msg.sender);                 
 }

 function random() private view returns(uint)          
 {      
  return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players)));                      
 }                                                

 function pickWinner() public 
 {
   uint index = random() % players.length;   
   address payable players[].transfer();                 // error on this line
 }                                            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using incorrect syntax on this line:

```
address payable players[].transfer();
```

I'm assuming that you want to transfer some amount to the `index`th player.

```
uint index = random() % players.length;
uint amount = address(this).balance; // whole ETH balance of this contract   
payable(players[index]).transfer(amount);
```

You can also use the `ether` unit to specify an absolute value.

```
uint amount = 0.01 ether;
```

Note that your `random()` function could be theoretically exploited by a dishonest miner if they have a big enough incentive. See the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67826884/1693192) for more into.